# VB Select command in sql

Tags: sql, vbscript

I'm using VB trying to access a database in MSACCESS.

I'm doing this really dumb thing:

```
SSQL9 = "select Username as docuser from Doctors where TreatmentField = '"&Treatment&"'"
        set Rs9 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
        Rs9.open SSQL9,conn
        Something=Rs9("docuser")
        Response.Write(Something)
```

And for some reason I get:

> ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'
>
> Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

While I'm *sure* there is a record. What causes the error?

Comment: It's quite simple: If both the `.EOF` and the `.BOF` properties of the record set are `True`, then the record set is empty, even if you expect something else.

Comment: Just curious: what will happen to your code if the `Treatment` variable has an apostrophe in it?  Make sure you think that through carefully.

Comment: @Joel he has to double it before

Comment: @bend_k - that catches most cases, but there are other ways to inject sql as well.

Comment: What happens if you use a literal for treatment eg `WHERE TreatmentField='OBGYN' ` ? Also you might like to consider cursor types when you get this problem solved : http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/met_rs_open.asp Not all cursor type support all actions. It can be useful to `Response.Write(SSQL9)` and run it through Access, being careful about wildcards. It can also be useful to `Response.Write(rs9(0).Name)` If it is any consolation, it is probably some simple problem that you will kick yourself about :)

Answer (score 1):

@eve: That looks more like VBScript than VB to me... Assuming `conn` is an `ADODB.Connection` object, you don't need to create a `RecordSet` object unless you're going to be using pagination, so you can rewrite your code sample as --

```
If Treatment <> "" Then
    SSQL9 = "SELECT Username as docuser FROM Doctors WHERE (TreatmentField = '" & Treatment & "')"
    Set Rs9 = con.Execute(SSQL9)
    If NOT Rs9.EOF Then
        Something = Rs9(0)
        Response.Write(Something)
    Else
        ' Empty recordset ' 
    End If
    Rs9.Close
Else
    Response.Write "No 'Treatment' input was sent"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I can identify my problem, however I have no idea why it's happening.  Once I execute the SELECT command, I don't get any record back, while I'm sure there is a record with that 'treatment' in the .mdb file. This is very weird.

Comment: Another thing - if I just select all usernames (without = treatment) I only get the first record. Strange!

Comment: @eve: You would only get the first record using that query, because you'll have to make a loop to get all the other records as well. Could you perhaps post the `Treatment` input you're sending and `Treatment` as it is stored in the database?

Comment: @eve: Try `SSQL9 = "SELECT Username as docuser FROM Doctors WHERE (TreatmentField LIKE '%" & Treatment & "%')"` and if you get your record, then the `Treatment` in the database has a space or a tab character in there...

Comment: @bernd_k: I should have said `code` instead of `query`, because that is what I meant in that comment. Since she's just printing out one of the records to the screen, it will appear as if only one record was found/retrieved, which is what the second part of my comment was about: creating a loop which will print out any other retrieved records.

Comment: Building the loop ought not be the problem, cf. my answer. Main problem is finding out why the where clause doesn't work as intended. I think Access is case insensitive similar to SQL-Server.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar task we use code like this:

```
Dim QD As adodb.Command
Dim rs As adodb.Recordset

Set QD = New adodb.Command
QD.CommandText = sql
QD.CommandType = adCmdText
QD.ActiveConnection = conn

Set rs = QD.Execute
```

**To track down the error proceed as follows:**

1. Select a value for treatment
2. Replace the parameter in the query with that value -- run the query in access
3. Try your VB Programm with the successfull tested query.
4. When the error still occurs its the VB else the query

**To get all the records you need some kind of loop**

```
Do While Not rs9.EOF
        Something=Rs9!docuser
        Response.Write(Something)
        RS9.MoveNext
Loop
```

**Changed code:**

now using Something=Rs9!docuser  Please try